# How can I use bootstrap grid with angular cli?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng2-bootstrap

I made:

```
npm install ng2-bootstrap --save
```

then opened angular-cli-build.js and added this line

```
vendorNpmFiles: [
       ..................
       'ng2-bootstrap/**/*.js',
        ....................
      ]
```

Wrote in src/system-config.ts

```
const map:any ={
         ..................
       'ng2-bootstrap': 'vendor/ng2-bootstrap',
        ....................

    }
```

and

```
 const packages: any = {
      'ng2-bootstrap': {
        format: 'cjs',
        defaultExtension: 'js',
        main: 'ng2-bootstrap.js'

      }

    };
```

But without the link from cdn

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

I can't use styles Bootstrap. Can I do something with it?

Answer (score 0):

ng2-bootstrap module is a bundle of Angular 2 components and directives which replaces the default bootstrap javascript. This means you don't need to include bootstrap javascript and jQuery in your Angular 2 application.

This module does not include bootstrap css. You will still need to include it in some way and the easiest solution is to add the cdn in your application. ng2-bootstrap will work perfectly with the default bootstrap css.

To include the bootstrap css you will need to add the following line to src/index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```